# run HTTPD LOG sample as BAM tenant

Tags: wso2, multi-tenant, wso2-bam

I found out that httpd log sample is not working as a tenant, with the exception of datasource not found.
Then I check the hive script, it defined the datasource but tenant cannot see this datasource. so I think that the datasource needs to be created, right? But in my opinion, I think this should be completed within the BAM automatically to exposed the default datasource to the tanent. What do you think?

Comment: I got some light from the official doc where I should add some lines in the script to identify the datasource. but in fact I am not sure if this can be done in other way?

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to [1] to know how to write a tenant specific Hive script.

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/display/BAM240/Writing+Hive+Script+as+Tenant

Answer (score 1):

You might need to add wso2 carbon data source as tenant. Please refer the following document.

http://docs.wso2.org/display/BAM240/Installing+Tenant+Toolbox